# WPF Path Borders Blurring

Tags: .net, wpf

While creating a button style I encountered the following display issue:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
 
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#F0F0F0">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Path x:Name="Mark" Stroke="Black" Data="M 0,0 L 10,0 L 10,10 L 0,10 Z" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                          UseLayoutRounding="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The line width should be 1 pixel in all directions. At the screenshot we can see that the left and bottom sides are 2 pixels wide. I tried not using `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased` (blurred borders):

[image]

And use `UseLayoutRounding="True"`+`SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` (blurred borders also):

[image]

I tried to determine the system DPI value for the window and the value that WPF knows:

```
PresentationSource presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window);                 
double wpfDpi = 96.0 * presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;                 
double currentDpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
```

Both values are the same (120) - the application knows about the scale.

Taget platform: NET Framework 4.5

OS: Windows 10 21H2

Comment: Why not just use a rectangle with transparent fill and 1px stroke?

Comment: @Andy When using Rectangle element the situation is similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blurring seems to be caused by the gap between pixel boundaries and the outer edge of a drawn line. Both `SnapsToDevicePixels` and `UseLayoutRounding` will make the location of an element in line with pixel boundaries but it does not necessarily mean the outer edge of border or stroke line of the element is aligned to pixel boundaries. In the case of Path, the line will be centered at the Path.

`RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` forcibly produces a clear line but its width varies depending on the distance of both edges of line from pixel boundaries.

To produce a clear line of a specified width, you can draw a line manually at [UIElement.OnRender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onrender) taking into account the gap from pixel boundaries. It is onerous but not impossible.

Or you can draw each line with a Rectangle filled with Brush and havig no stroke. Since the location of each Rectangle will be aligned to pixel boundaries, all lines will be clear.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <Grid Width="10" Height="10"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" Height="10"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Height="1"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" Height="10"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10" Height="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I think there is still room for improvement but it should work.

**EDIT**

If you choose to draw manually at OnRender (I am not recommending it because it could be too onerous), you can get help of [GuidelineSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.guidelineset) which would simplify the calculation in combination with [DrawingContext.PushGuidelineSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushguidelineset).

Here is an example of plain square.

```cs
public class OneGridControl : Control
{
    public OneGridControl()
    {
        this.Width = 10;
        this.Height = 10;
    }

    protected override void OnDpiChanged(DpiScale oldDpi, DpiScale newDpi)
    {
        base.OnDpiChanged(oldDpi, newDpi);

        this.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var line = new Pen(this.Foreground, 1D);
        var lineRadius = line.Thickness / 2;

        // Prepare rectangles.
        var baseRect = new Rect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        var actualRect = new Rect(
            baseRect.X + lineRadius,
            baseRect.Y + lineRadius,
            baseRect.Width - lineRadius * 2,
            baseRect.Height - lineRadius * 2);

        // Set guidelines.
        var guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(baseRect.Left);
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(baseRect.Right);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(baseRect.Top);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(baseRect.Bottom);

        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);

        // Draw rectangle.
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, line, actualRect);

        drawingContext.Pop();

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. But what if the figure is much more complex than a simple rectangle? Draw everything on DrawingContext?

Comment: It is up to how you can place all lines nicely but regardless of the way to draw lines, the more complex the shape becomes, the more difficult it will be to align all lines in line with pixel boundaries under various DPIs. On the other hand, I think the more complex the shape is, the less the blurring in part will be noticeable.

Comment: Well, what if the shape is simple, but there are a lot of straight lines? All descriptions of figures are presented in Path Markup Language.

Comment: I wanted to say that in fact, in the `Path.Data` property I have more straight lines than 4. I was expecting a solution in which it is enough to simply set certain dependency properties correctly))

Comment: Something like `SnapsToDevicePixels` and `UseLayoutRounding` properties. I understand that there will be no such solution. Needs to be drawn manually. Are there any ready solutions for clear drawing lines on `DrawingContext` with using data from `Path.Data` property?

Comment: I see. You are blaming the lack of such built-in property. It is understandable. And I don't know such ready-made solution.

Comment: Okey, and what's about drawing lines on DrawingContext with using data from `Path.Data` property?

Comment: AFAIK, no such ready-made solution as I wrote.

Comment: I thought you answered this about the Path properties related to rendering. I'll have to draw it myself then.

Comment: Please, look at this: https://pastebin.com/tKrwMsCh. Problem still exists: https://ibb.co/9p6VJ9R. What's wrong with drawing lines in my code? How to take into the pixel boundaries?

Comment: You need to calculate the possible gaps between the edges of each line and pixel boundaries and slightly adjust the location and width of the line to offset those gaps. It will be onerous as I warned.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows you to draw line segments in Path with snaps to pixels:

```
/// <summary>
/// Draws a series of connected clear lines.
/// </summary>
class ClearPath : Shape {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Data", typeof(Geometry), typeof(ClearPath), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender),
        new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidData));

    public Geometry Data {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    private static bool IsValidData(object value) {

        if (value == null) return true;

        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.AddGeometry((Geometry)value);

        foreach (var figure in pathGeometry.Figures) {
            foreach (var segment in figure.Segments) {
                if (!(segment is PolyLineSegment) && !(segment is LineSegment)) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry {
        get { return Data ?? Geometry.Empty; }
    }

    private double CurrentDpiX = 96;
    private double PixelSize = 1;
    private double HalfPixelSize = 0.5;
    private Point SubpixelOffset = new Point(0, 0);

    public ClearPath() {

        System.Drawing.Graphics g = new System.Windows.Forms.Label().CreateGraphics();
        CurrentDpiX = g.DpiX;
        PixelSize = 96.0 / CurrentDpiX;
        HalfPixelSize = PixelSize / 2;

        LayoutUpdated += delegate {
            Window window = App.GetAncestorOfType<Window>(this);
            Point controlOffset = TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), window);
            SubpixelOffset = new Point(ModByPixel(controlOffset.X), ModByPixel(controlOffset.Y));
            InvalidateVisual();
        };
    }

    private Pen GetPen() {
        Pen pen = new Pen();
        pen.Thickness = Math.Abs(StrokeThickness);
        pen.Brush = Stroke;
        pen.StartLineCap = StrokeStartLineCap;
        pen.EndLineCap = StrokeEndLineCap;
        pen.DashCap = StrokeDashCap;
        pen.LineJoin = StrokeLineJoin;
        pen.MiterLimit = StrokeMiterLimit;
        return pen;
    }

#if NET461_OR_GREATER
    protected override void OnDpiChanged(DpiScale oldDpi, DpiScale newDpi) {
        CurrentDpiX = newDpi.DpiScaleX;
        PixelSize = 96.0 / CurrentDpiX;
        HalfPixelSize = PixelSize / 2;
        base.OnDpiChanged(oldDpi, newDpi);
    }
#endif

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {

        if (DefiningGeometry == Geometry.Empty) return;

        Pen pen = GetPen();
        pen.Thickness = SnapToPixels(pen.Thickness);

        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.AddGeometry(DefiningGeometry);

        foreach (var figure in pathGeometry.Figures) {

            Point startPoint = figure.StartPoint;
            foreach (var segment in figure.Segments) {

                PointCollection points;
                if (segment is PolyLineSegment)
                    points = (segment as PolyLineSegment).Points;
                else if (segment is LineSegment)
                    points = new PointCollection() { (segment as LineSegment).Point };
                else continue;

                foreach (var point in points) {
                    Point point_ = point;
                    SnapLineToPixels(pen, ref startPoint, ref point_);
                    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, point_);
                    startPoint = point;
                }
            }

            if (figure.IsClosed) {
                Point endPoint = figure.StartPoint;
                SnapLineToPixels(pen, ref startPoint, ref endPoint);
                drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, endPoint);
            }
        }
    }

    private double ModByPixel(double size) =>
        (size * 1000) % (PixelSize * 1000) / 1000;

    private bool IsOddPixels(double size) =>
        (size * 1000) % (2 * PixelSize * 1000) != 0;

    private double SnapToPixels(double size) {
        size += PixelSize / 2;
        return (int)((size * 1000) / (PixelSize * 1000)) * PixelSize;
    }

    private void SnapLineToPixels(Pen pen, ref Point startPoint, ref Point endPoint) {

        double correctionX = -SubpixelOffset.X;
        double correctionY = -SubpixelOffset.Y;

        if (IsOddPixels(pen.Thickness)) {
            correctionX += HalfPixelSize;
            correctionY += HalfPixelSize;
        }

        startPoint.X += correctionX;
        startPoint.Y += correctionY;
        endPoint.X += correctionX;
        endPoint.Y += correctionY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work. But when I tested your ClearPath with `<RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,25,25"/>`, it produced blurry lines at 125%, 150% and 175% DPIs. At 200%, lines were clear. It might be unrealistic to create a solution which works with any Geometry at any DPI. Perhaps you would need to specify the conditions where ClearPath works.